# Extending User Model in Django Issues

Tags: python, django

I'm currently running Django 1.6 and trying to extend the users model using this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField
The only way I can get it to work is if I create an AdditionalUser object and go backwards to reach the User model.

I used this code:

```
from django.db import models 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AdditionalUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

but when I try to do the following, it gives me False:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
hasattr(user, 'hobby')
False
```

I already ran syncdb after I created this new model. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No, not according to the docs.  `User.objects.get(pk=1)` is correct.  What is the output from running hasattr(user, 'additionaluser')

Comment: I think so. What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User` object does not have the attributes you specify in `AdditionalUser`. However, it does have a `additionaluser` attribute:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
# create the AdditionalUser object
additional = AdditionalUser.objects.create(user=user)
hasattr(user.additionaluser, 'hobby')
True
```

The documentation on OneToOneField says [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField):

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.
>   (...)
>   If you do not specify the the related_name argument for the
>   OneToOneField, Django will use the lower-case name of the current
>   model as default value.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'hobby' property does not exist in the User object, then you will always get False.

Try this:

```
user = AdditionalUser.objects.filter(user__id=1)[0]
hasattr(user, 'hobby')
```

Comment: Assuming that there are Users and AdditionalUsers already inside your DB.